# preg_replace to strip all query strings for a matching host within an HTML file

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Given a static HTML file, containing links with query strings from multiple hosts/domains, how can I use `preg_replace` to strip all query strings for a certain host only?

- DOMDocument is not an option in this case.
- All query strings are to be removed, leaving only a URL segment `/foo/` or a filepath, `http://example.com/bar.jpg`

**Example input:**

```
<span><a href="http://domainneedingstripping.com/path/file.jpg?string=blah">x</a>
</span><img src="http://otherdomain.com?dontStripThis=true" />
<p>And much more content as in a full HTML doc</p>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<span><a href="http://domainneedingstripping.com/path/file.jpg">x</a>
</span><img src="http://otherdomain.com?dontStripThis=true" />
<p>And much more content as in a full HTML doc</p>
```

^ note only one domain’s query strings are wanted to be stripped, preserving any URLs from other hosts that may contain query strings

I have found regex examples to remove query strings from singular URLs, but not from a full document. I think with one of those, I can figure out how to limit it to a specific host/domain.

Comment: How do these querys look like?

Comment: Please add examples of input, desired output and things you have already tried

Comment: Just wondering, why is DOMDocument is not an option in this case?

Comment: DOMDocument is not possible as the input can sometimes be invalid HTML, which needs to remain invalid as cleaning it can change the rendering drastically

Comment: Does this need to be done server-side? It might well be easier with JS to just loop over `document.querySelectorAll('a')` and apply the changes to the `href` attribute as required rather than having to attempt to parse an entire (invalid) HTML block with PHP/RegEx.

Comment: Server-side is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Tested php 5.6 netbeans 8.1]

```
$string = '
    <span><a href="http://domainneedingstripping.com/path/file.jpg?string=blah">x</a></span>
    <img src="http://otherdomain.com?dontStripThis=true" />
    <p>And much more content as in a full HTML doc</p>
    <span><a href="http://domainneedingstripping.com/otherpath/otherfile.jpg?string=blah">x</a></span>';

$pattern = "/(['|\"])(http:\/\/domainneedingstripping.com)(.+?)\?(.+?)(['|\"])/im";

$replacement = "\${1}\${2}\${3}\${5}";

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

The result is:

```
<span><a href="http://domainneedingstripping.com/path/file.jpg">x</a></span>
<img src="http://otherdomain.com?dontStripThis=true" />
<p>And much more content as in a full HTML doc</p>
<span><a href="http://domainneedingstripping.com/otherpath/otherfile.jpg">x</a></span>
```

This can be a solution but the variables in the HTML file can be a lot so I suggest you http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

This solution is for only a particular domain.

Comment: In the example shown, there are two domains/hosts. I need to only strip the query strings from every URL matching one particular host. There could be many different hosts in the HTML files I parse.

Comment: Can I add domainneedingstripping.com into your pattern to only match one host?

Comment: @LeonStafford Updated the script! To use with care, like I said there can be a lot of variables and possible errors in the Html, that can break the regular expression replacement.

Comment: As per this, the matching is working great: https://regexr.com/3qor8 But I'm not seeing any substitution happening in my code or when running your code verbatim.

Comment: This was just an example, I do not know your code. If you execute my example code with PHP 5.6 from the command line or from a browser the result is correct. If you are using any other language different from PHP or version you have to read the documentation about the replacement syntax.

Comment: Thanks @q81 - I was running it within a script with some other code, so that may have interfered. Works perfectly via CLI

Answer (score -1):

In PHP, with the help of the [file_get_contents function](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php), you can get the content of your .html:

```
$content = file_get_contents ("myFile.html");
```

Then there is the [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.server.php) global variable that can give you the IP:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Then it's all about using your `preg_replace()` as you would like.